# Efficient double iteration over array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code, where points is many lines by 3 cols list of lists, coorRadius is a radius within which I want to find the local coordinate maxima, and localCoordinateMaxima is an array where I store the i's of these maxima:

```
for i,x in enumerate(points):
        check = 1
        for j,y in enumerate(points):
            if linalg.norm(x-y) <= coorRadius and x[2] < y[2]:
                check = 0

        if check == 1:
            localCoordinateMaxima.append(i)

    print localCoordinateMaxima
```

Unfortunately, this takes forever when I have several thousand points, I am looking for a way to speed it up. I tried to do it with if all() condition, however I didn't manage it and I am not even sure it will be more efficient. Could you guys propose a way to make it faster?

Best!

Comment: Is `points` a numpy array? Are the data-points on a grid?

Comment: You can do this using matrix to store the norms and find the indices that attend your conditions, without for loops...

Comment: points is a list of lists, with the coords in float format, so they are not exactly on a grid.

Comment: But I think it could easily be turned into a numpy array, if this is going to help?

Comment: I'm too tired from XCOM to write up a proper answer, but http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

Comment: Unifrtunately the link doesn't load.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be down right now. You can read about k-d trees on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) while SciPy's site isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search for neighbors is best done using a KDTree.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

tree = cKDTree(points)
pairs = tree.query_pairs(coorRadius)
```

Now `pairs` is a set of two item tuples `(i, j)`, where `i < j` and `points[i]` and `points[j]` are within `coorRadius` of each other. You can now simply iterate over these, which will likely be a much smaller set than the `len(points)**2` you are currently iterating over:

```
is_maximum = [True] * len(points)
for i, j in pairs:
    if points[i][2] < points[j][2]:
        is_maximum[i] = False
    elif points[j][2] < points[i][2]:
        is_maximum[j] = False
localCoordinateMaxima, = np.nonzero(is_maximum)
```

This can be further sped up by vectorizing it:

```
pairs = np.array(list(pairs))
pairs = np.vstack((pairs, pairs[:, ::-1]))
pairs = pairs[np.argsort(pairs[:, 0])]
is_z_smaller = points[pairs[:, 0], 2] < points[pairs[:, 1], 2]
bins, = np.nonzero(pairs[:-1, 0] != pairs[1:, 0])
bins = np.concatenate(([0], bins+1))
is_maximum = np.logical_and.reduceat(is_z_smaller, bins)
localCoordinateMaxima, = np.nonzero(is_maximum)
```

The above code assumes that every point has at least one neighbor within `coorRadius`. If that is not the case, you need to slightly complicate things:

```
pairs = np.array(list(pairs))
pairs = np.vstack((pairs, pairs[:, ::-1]))
pairs = pairs[np.argsort(pairs[:, 0])]
is_z_smaller = points[pairs[:, 0], 2] < points[pairs[:, 1], 2]
bins, = np.nonzero(pairs[:-1, 0] != pairs[1:, 0])
has_neighbors = pairs[np.concatenate(([True], bins)), 0]
bins = np.concatenate(([0], bins+1))
is_maximum = np.ones((len(points),), bool)
is_maximum[has_neighbors] &= np.logical_and.reduceat(is_z_smaller, bins)
localCoordinateMaxima, = np.nonzero(is_maximum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version of your code just tightened-up a bit:

```
for i, x in enumerate(points):
    x2 = x[2]
    for y in points:
        if linalg.norm(x-y) <= coorRadius and x2 < y[2]:
            break
    else:
        localCoordinateMaxima.append(i)
    print localCoordinateMaxima
```

Changes:

- Factor-out the `x[2]` lookup.
- The *j* variable was unused.
- Add a *break* for an early-out
- Use a for-else construct instead of a flag variable

Comment: Thanks, I am new to python, does the x2 = x[2] make it faster, or is it just for tidiness?

Comment: It makes it faster.  The ``x[2]`` lookup takes time so it is best to hoist the loop-invariant code out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

With numpy this is not too hard. You can do it with a single (long) expression, if you want:

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array(points)
localCoordinateMaxima = np.where(np.all((np.linalg.norm(points-points[None,:], axis=-1) >
                                         coorRadius) |
                                        (points[:,2] >= points[:,None,2]),
                                        axis=-1))
```

The algorithm your current code implements is essentially `where(not(any(w <= x and y < z)))`. If you distribute the `not` through the logical operations inside of it (using Demorgan's laws), you can avoid one level of nesting by flipping the inequalities, getting `where(all(w > x or y >= z)))`.

`w` is a matrix of norms applied to the differences of the points broadcast together. `x` is a constant. `y` and `z` are both arrays with the third coordinates of the points, shaped so that they broadcast together into the same shape as `w`.

Comment: Whilst less readable, this is by far the more efficient of the two answers as

Comment: I don't think efficient is the right adjective. This is less efficient than the early breaking out of loops in Raymond's answer, but is likely to be faster for smaller data sets.

Comment: Thanks, it looks very clever, however this does not give the same answers as my code.

Comment: My data sets usually have several thousand points, not sure what you mean by smaller.